# position or display property that let's the block not react to others

Tags: css, position, display

I want to position a label above and to the left edge of a text field. I put them together in a div. The only problem left is that I need the correct position or display attribute that the input field doesn't react to the label. In that way, I could write `text-align:left` or `float: left` to position the label at the very edge of the div and thus at the very edge of the label.

```
<div class="AlignLeft">
  <input type="text" id="1" name="name" maxlength="100" required>
  <label for="name" id="1">Align label left</label><br>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**without CSS**

1. to make that on click of the label, the input will be focused.

you will need that your `<label>` element, have the [`for=""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for) attribute

 this attribute needs the same `id=""` as the input. (not the `name=""`)

> for attribute (docs): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for

2. for making the `<label>` be on the left

- put the label before the `<input>`
- make the input nested inside the `<label>`, then insert a span before the `<input>`

**no css solution:**

```html
<div>
  <label for="myId"> <!-- put here the id -->
     <span>this is the label text</span> <!-- the text -->
     <input type="text" id="myId"> <!-- input -->
  </label>
</div>
```

---

**with CSS**

if you can't change the HTML structure, then follow this second way (using CSS)

1. The `float` property, you showed before seems to work fine.

> so just change the `for=""` attribute to be equal to the `id=""` of `<input>`

```css
.AlignLeft label {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
    <div class="AlignLeft">
        <input type="text" id="1">
        <label for="1">Align label left</label><br>
    </div>
```

2. or use CSS [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) with the direction of `reverse`

> using `flexbox` you have other advantages like `gap` or centering, and so on...

```css
.AlignLeft {
    display: flex;
    /* solve the problem (now the text is on the left side) */
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    /* you can center easily using flex, or in this case put it on the left of the page */
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    /* add a gap is easier with flex */
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="AlignLeft">
        <input type="text" id="1">
        <label for="1">Align label left</label><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: The CSS way doesn't seem to work for me, so tryed the HTML. This works, but it kinda messes everything up. The element isn't at the position it was before, the text is neither clickable nor is the width correct. Any idea why?

Comment: can you share me a screenshot of what is look now, or the site link (so I can debug it)

Comment: It's in the question. Sorry it's german

Comment: Ok I found a solution: I used your CSS, but instead of justify-content: center I had to write left. That way, it wasn't centered anymore. So I used padding to fix it. Thank you!